# Make NPoco consider Database default values

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, npoco

Given the following `table` in my database (PostgreSQL)

```
CREATE TABLE produkt (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name VARCHAR(50),
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT timezone('utc'::text, now())
);

ALTER TABLE produkt ADD CONSTRAINT produkt_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

I want to use NPoco to access the data using this poco

```
[TableName("produkt"), PrimaryKey("id", AutoIncrement = true)]
public class Product
{
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Column("created_at")]
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }
}
```

Now, when I call

```
var product = new Product
{
    Name = "My new Product"
};

Database.Insert(product);  // or Database.Save<Product>(product);
```

The `created_at`-column is `-infinity`, even though the `default` value has been declared. Is there any way to fix this? One alternative would be to set the Date within the application, but I would rather have this functionality beeing realized using the `default` value in the DB.

Answer (score -2):

Try makin CreatedAt nullable:

`[Column("created_at")]
public Nullable<DateTime> CreatedAt { get; set; }`

or set its value in constructor as seen
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22457887/set-default-datetime-value-with-petapoco/22500703#22500703) .

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer. I tried both `Nullable<DateTime>` as well as `DateTime?`, but neither did the trick. Maybe it is a Postgre Issue. Setting the Date in the CTor would be an Alternative I know, but I would prefer setting it in the DB to stay consistent. Anyway, thank you very much!